# Why is Bloc trigerring multple times the same state?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm new to **Bloc** and I noticed that when a state changes it changes multiple times for one state change, let me explain, so for example I have this set up, on my `login_page.dart` I have a `BlocListener` which bascially shows a snackbar and navigates to another page when the operation of logining has been successful:

```dart
BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
  listener: (context, state) {
    dev.log('listener login page: $state');

    if (state is AuthLoadingState) {
      loadingDialog(context);
    } else if (state is AuthLoadedState) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
        ),
      );
      showSnackBar(
          message: 'Logged in successfully', isError: false);
    } else if (state is AuthErrorState) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      showSnackBar(message: state.message, isError: true);
    }
  },
  child: AuthButtonWidget(
    formKey: _formKey,
    onPressed: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(
          LogInWithEmailAndPasswordEvent(
            email: _emailController.text,
            password: _passwordController.text,
          ),
        );
      }
    },
    text: 'Log In',
  ),
),
```

On my `home_page.dart` I have one `BlocConsumer` which listens to an event, shows a snackbar and navigates back to the login page when a button (to log out) has been pressed:

```dart
BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
  listener: (context, state) {
    dev.log('listener home page: $state');
    if (state is AuthLoadingState) {
      loadingDialog(context);
    } else if (state is AuthLoggedOutState) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const LoginPage(),
        ),
      );
      showSnackBar(message: 'Logged out successfully', isError: false);
    } else if (state is AuthErrorState) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      showSnackBar(message: state.message, isError: true);
    }
  },
  buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
  builder: (context, state) {
    dev.log('builder home page: $state');

    if (state is AuthLoadedState) {
      return const HomePageWidget();
    } else if (state is AuthErrorState) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('AuthErrorState'),
      );
    } else {
      return const HomePageWidget();
    }
  },
);
```

The `HomePageWidget()` is simply a column with a floating action button that disconnects the user. For further informations, here is my Bloc:

```dart
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordUsecase signUpWithEmailAndPassword;
  final LogInWithEmailAndPasswordUsecase logInWithEmailAndPassword;
  final LogOutUsecase logOut;
  AuthBloc(
    this.signUpWithEmailAndPassword,
    this.logInWithEmailAndPassword,
    this.logOut,
  ) : super(AuthInitial()) {
    on<AuthEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordEvent) {
        emit(AuthLoadingState());

        final failureOrUnit = await signUpWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password,
          name: event.name,
        );

        emit(_mapFailureOrPostsState(either: failureOrUnit));
      } else if (event is LogInWithEmailAndPasswordEvent) {
        emit(AuthLoadingState());

        final failureOrUnit = await logInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password,
        );

        emit(_mapFailureOrPostsState(either: failureOrUnit));
      } else if (event is LogOutEvent) {
        emit(AuthLoadingState());

        final failureOrUnit = await logOut();

        emit(_mapFailureOrPostsState(
          either: failureOrUnit,
          isLogOut: true,
        ));
      }
    });
  }
}

AuthState _mapFailureOrPostsState({
  required Either<Failure, Unit> either,
  bool isLogOut = false,
}) {
  return either.fold(
    (failure) => AuthErrorState(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
    (_) {
      if (isLogOut) {
        return AuthLoggedOutState();
      } else {
        return AuthLoadedState();
      }
    },
  );
}

String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
  if (failure is SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure) {
    switch (failure.code) {
      case 'email-already-in-use':
        return EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'invalid-email':
        return INVALID_EMAIL_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'operation-not-allowed':
        return OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'weak-password':
        return WEAK_PASSWORD_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      default:
        return SIGN_UP_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
    }
  } else if (failure is LogInWithEmailAndPasswordFailure) {
    switch (failure.code) {
      case 'invalid-email':
        return INVALID_EMAIL_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'user-disabled':
        return USER_IS_DISABLED_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'user-not-found':
        return USER_NOT_FOUND_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      case 'wrong-password':
        return WRONG_PASSWORD_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
      default:
        return LOG_IN_WITH_EMAIL_AND_PASSWORD_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
    }
  } else if (failure is LogOutFailure) {
    return LOG_OUT_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  } else if (failure is OfflineFailure) {
    return OFFLINE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  } else if (failure is EmptyCacheFailure) {
    return EMPTY_CACHE_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  } else {
    return UNEXPECTED_FAILURE_MESSAGE;
  }
}
```

When I press on the buttons it workes perfectly fine but the it shows multiple snackbars (for example when I log out it can show 5 snackbars telling me "logging out successful" one after the other) I have two questions, why are these snackbars showing mutlple times, and what can I change on my code to remove bugs ?

Comment: I suppose showSnackBar call ScaffoldMessenger.of(context) somewhere, do you see printed multiple times dev.log('listener home page: $state')?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happen because you register you Bloc at your main (it can be your main.dart or your class of your main app)
correct me if i'm wrong.

if we register it at the main, the bloc will become a global.
So if you using Bloc listener at 1 page, and you call that bloc again in another page, it will call what result you set at your listener (in this case you show snackBar).

So register your bloc only at the page that you need to use that listener.

Example :

```js
class ScreenLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenLogin({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => sl<LoginBloc>()), // Register Your Bloc Here
    ], child: const Content());
  }
}

class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  const Content({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if(state is LoginSuccess){
            //Do Something
          }
        },
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Remove your register Bloc from here

```js
void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.initialRoute}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => sl<LoginBloc>(), //Remove the Bloc From Here
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Bla bla bla bla ',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: "Roboto",
          primaryColor: const Color(0xFFFC8F7B),
        ),
        initialRoute: initialRoute,
        routes: AppNavigation.routes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so I only need to put a bloc provider (to register the AuthBloc) on the page when I need to bloc ? In my case I need the AuthBloc on multiple pages (login page, sign up page, forgot password page, verify email page) so I need to put bloc providers on all these screens individually ?

Comment: For your case, my answer is yes. Because when you register you bloc at main, the bloc is become a parent of all your project (this is why, when you use bloc listener to navigate or show snackbar it can run multiple times when you come again to the screen that you put listener). 

I Suggest you to use 1 Bloc to 1 Transaction (1 Flow). 
So in your Case 
Login -> LoginBloc
SignUp -> SignUpBloc
Forgot Pass -> ForgotPassBloc 

Or Register the Auth Bloc on multiplepages

Comment: So I will create n folders, each one hold a bloc, the LoginBloc, the SignUpBloc, the ForgotPasswordBloc, and inside the blocs I can define events like SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordEvent, SignUpWithGoogleEvent, SignUpWithFacebookBloc etc etc ? and in the main.dart I use the multi bloc provider  and register all the blocs ? Is it not bad to use too many blocs ?

Comment: If you say bad or not bad. That's back to you, because for me. Better to use one bloc for one flow. But if you think that using 1 bloc to do more than one flow its up to you. 

Just remember this, if you want to use the bloc as a global bloc (more than 1 page, then register it at the main.page) if u only one page and using listener, just register it at the page. If you want to use only one bloc and do more than one flow, dont emit same state if success or failed